# Best reinforcement learning algorithm for continuous state space and discrete action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have an environment with continuous state space and discrete action space (two actions like 0 or 1). What is the best RL algorithm for this case?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on the reward structure; state and action spaces alone do not define the level of easiness for a problem and one cannot say anything about a good algorithm yet. I would first try `DQN`. If it did not work, I would try `A2C` or `A3C`. If they also did not work, I would try `PPO`.

If neither of them worked, you need to provide more information about the environment. Maybe it needs a special exploration technique.

You can find a very high level description of them at [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-algorithms.html). The link of the corresponding papers and their code is available on the link.

Comment: What about recent algorithms like TD3 and SAC? The authors claim their methods can learn the optimal policy in fewer time steps than the ones you mentioned.

Comment: `TD3` is an improvement over `DDPG` which both are used for the continues control. `SAC` papers shows that on some environment it achieves better results than `PPO`; however, as I have seen in papers people still use `PPO`. Anyway, `SAC` is also implemented in `Ray`, you can try that one too. 
My suggestion is that do not mess up with complex algorithm at the first point. Start with the easy ones, see if works, otherwise learn why it does not work and then choose the next algorithm.